# Solr query syntax. is "range:[1000 to 1000]" equal to "range:1000"?

Tags: solr

I'm studying Solr and got some question about Solr query syntax:

is `range:[1000 to 1000]`equivalent to `range:1000` ?

Comment: I don't think `range:1000` works, it's not the proper syntax. Anyways `:[1000 TO 1000]` means the query will check the field whose value is 1000.

Comment: `range:1000` is completely valid syntax - it just queries a field for the value 1000. They should be identical for most native types.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they should be identical.

There might be some border line case with imprecision in some types, but I can't see how that would change this behavior for indexed fields.

Comment: Range search might be a bit slower. Since it is a more complex algorithm.